# Python - "No module named" error

Tags: python, module, named

I'm working with a scientific package called TheCannon.
It's all written in Python, and I've installed it using pip.

Until two days ago, it worked perfectly.
Today, when I tried to use it, this happened:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 4, in <module>
    from TheCannon import dataset
ImportError: No module named TheCannon
```

I have already uninstalled and installed it again, and nothing changed.
Does anyone have any idea why python is not finding the package anymore and how to solve it?
Thank you.

Comment: Chances are you have multiple python versions installed, and your pip is using a different one than the one you are invoking this from.  Or (similar problem) different virtual environments.  As far as solving it goes, it depends on which OS you are using, etc.

Comment: What python and what operating system are you using? What changes did you make? If you're on Windows, have you checked your path? Are you sure the capitalisation is correct?

Comment: Check the path and make sure you don't have multiple python versions.

Comment: That's not the case. TheCannon's folder is inside Python2.7 folder, and I try to run my code using "$ python2.7 test2.py"

Comment: You can also open a python shell and see what you're path is: `import sys; print (sys.path)`.

Comment: Also try running this pip command to check where it has installed TheCannon:  `pip show TheCannon`.  This should have a 'Location' field where it says where you have it.  Make sure you don't have a pip which is pip3, you might want to use pip2.7 then, if it exists.

Comment: @Velmont, just did it and found the location. Do I have to insert it in the path? How do I do this on ubuntu?

Comment: @GeehSaviñón You should say what `print sys.path` gave you, plus what location pip gave you.  It seems like you might have something weird in your setup.

Comment: pip gave me:
    Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: and print sys.path:
['', '/scisoft/share/gildas-exe-apr11h/pc-fedora11-gfortran/python', '/scisoft/lib/python27.zip', '/scisoft/lib/python2.7', '/scisoft/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/scisoft/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/scisoft/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/scisoft/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/scisoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/scisoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Numeric', '/scisoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/scisoft/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-ansi']

Comment: Yep, we have a competing Python install taking the default Python path while pip updates for a different install. Make sure the script is working from the proper Python interpreter.

Using 'python -c "import sys; print sys.executable"' will tell you the interpreter in the future.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh it gave me "/scisoft/bin/python" which is clearly not the Python 2.7 folder where the packages are installed. What do I do to change it?

Comment: @GeehSaviñón, you need to change the Python environment variable to point to the C:\\Python27\\python.exe entry, which can be set as follows:
https://superuser.com/questions/25037/change-environment-variables-as-standard-user#25038

You can also use the full path rather than "Python".

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh thank you, but these instructions are for windows. I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, this is a path issue.

On Ubuntu, this is quite easy to fix. To find out the path of the current Python executable, do:

```
$ which python
# this will probably give you /usr/bin/python or /usr/local/bin/python by default, in your case, probably something quite different
/usr/bin/python
```

Then you need change the link the proper Python executable to this location.

```
# move to symlink to another file
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python_bak
# then relink the default Python on Ubuntu to the original
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

The default Python executable in Ubuntu for the system is at /usr/bin/python2.7, so preferably symlink this to the path "which python" gives. (Also, by # I mean a comment, not superuser).

If you need to undo this, just undo the moved symlink by:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/local/bin/python_bak /usr/local/bin/python
```

Also... don't ever link Python3 as the default Python on Ubuntu, just like how you would not do Python2 as the default install on Arch.